# Can anyone help with the stamp/seal on this print?

Tags: translation

This is stamp/seal is in the lower right corner of a rather large print. Can anyone tell me what is means or what it says? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“馬到成功”, roughly means

when the horse arrives, gains success immediately

[https://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/dictView.jsp?ID=26894&q=1&word=馬到成功](https://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/dictView.jsp?ID=26894&q=1&word=%E9%A6%AC%E5%88%B0%E6%88%90%E5%8A%9F)

Comment: I usually hear people say [馬到功成](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A6%AC%E5%88%B0%E5%8A%9F%E6%88%90) (Synonyms with 馬到成功 )

Comment: @TangHo, moi aussi lah  i leant, heard & used “馬到功成” all my life